stringdist::amatch not returning the closest match?
I have the following vector:
Filebase = c("20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001", "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000002", "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000003","20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000004", "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000005", "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000006")

I want to find the closest match with a second vector:
lswav = c("20230523POL3XXXXXX000001_20230523.wav", "20230523POL3XXXXXX000002_20230523.wav", "20230523POL3XXXXXX000003_20230523.wav", "20230523POL3XXXXXX000004_20230523.wav", "20230523POL3XXXXXX000005_20230523.wav", "20230523POL3XXXXXX000006_20230523.wav")

As you can see, the strings "000001", "000002", "000003", and so on, are the key.
To find the match I use stringdist::amatch :
Filebase[amatch(Filebase, lswav, maxDist = Inf)]

This returns
[1] "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001"  
[4] "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001"

While I expected
[1] "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000001" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000002" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000003"  
[4] "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000004" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000005" "20230523-POL3XXXXXX-000006"

So I read more about the options of amatch. It is possible to play with the method and the weights. So I tried all different methods. While the result may vary, it is never what I want.
Then I tried to play with the weights but I am lost in what is more important in my case. I think that deletions are ok (d = 0.1) but that insertion, substitution and transposition should be penalised (i = 1, s = 1, t = 1). This did not help.
I could not figure out how to properly use amatch in my case.
Of course I could prepare one of the two vectors to ressemble more the second vector to facilitate matching (e.g. only keeping the key "000001" in the first element). I tried that:
FileKEY = substr(Filebase, nchar(Filebase) -5, 
                                 nchar(Filebase))
FileKEY[amatch(FileKEY, lswav, maxDist = Inf)]


[1] "000001" "000001" "000001" "000004" "000001" "000006"

I tried also playing with method and weights but again I could not figure out what combination I should use.

Hi - this is a reasonable question until this part: I don't know what kind of data I will have in the future. Thus I would like to find a matching method that works in this case and that will work in other cases as well. As it stands, I am going to vote to close this question as needing focus. It's possible to find a method that will match the strings in this case (remove punctuation, see if one is a substring of the other), but finding a matching method that will work in any future case is not possible.

That being said you can take the lead and give your collaborators clear instructions on the format and then be sure what you get. This way future problems will be much easier to detect since you have a clearly defined canvas.

You can try sapply(gsub(".+-.+-(\\d+$)", "\\1", Filebase), grep, x=lswav, value=T).
